# Change value of variable by reference

Tags: swift, pointers

Hi I have 4 variables and I want to refer to one of them depending on some conditions, my current code looks as follows:

```
switch color {
    case .Azul:
        botonACambiar.tintColor = colores.salidaAzul
        if backTees == true {
            if option == 1{self.colorHcpBackTees1 = .Azul} else{self.colorHcpBackTees2 = .Azul}
        } else {
            if option == 1{self.colorHcpFrontTees1 = .Azul} else{self.colorHcpFrontTees2 = .Azul}
        }

    ...
    ...

    case . Cafe:
        botonACambiar.tintColor = colores.salidaMarron
        if backTees == true {
            if option == 1{self.colorHcpBackTees1 = .Cafe} else{self.colorHcpBackTees2 = .Cafe}
        } else {
            if option == 1{self.colorHcpFrontTees1 = .Cafe} else{self.colorHcpFrontTees2 = .Cafe}
        }
    }
```

---

I have around 8 options, and as you can see it gets kind of messy.
So far I only have 4 different variables that i might manipulate:
Option 1 & 2 for **FrontTees** & option 1 & 2 for **BackTees**, but in the future the app might support more options and more colors for front and back tees.

This 4 values are saved in the app and because of this I need to keep track of them individually, thus I have the four variables:

```
var colorHcpBackTees1: ColoresDeSalidas = .Negra
var colorHcpBackTees2: ColoresDeSalidas = .Blanca
var colorHcpFrontTees1: ColoresDeSalidas = .Roja
var colorHcpFrontTees2: ColoresDeSalidas = .Blanca
```

---

Each with their default values, it would be nice to have a way of initializing a reference variable in such a way that I could do something like:

```
var choice: ColoresDeSalidas{
        if backTees && option == 1 { return self.colorHcpBackTees1}
        if backTees && option == 2 { return self.colorHcpBackTees2}
        if !backTees && option == 1 { return self.colorHcpFrontTees1}
        if !backTees && option == 2 { return self.colorHcpFrontTees2}
    }
```

And simply use the variable choice to manipulate the value of the right variable

Comment: Can you add the `ColoresDeSalidas` enum to the code, as I think extending this will give what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a `ReferenceWritableKeyPath`.

> What is a `ReferenceWritableKeyPath`?

Think of it as a precise description of a property in a `class` or `struct`.  A real world example would be *The Empire State Building* instead of the address which would be *20 W 34th St, New York, NY 10001*.  You could tell either one to a cab driver and she could take you there.

A `ReferenceWritableKeyPath` is a generic type.  You need to specify the `class` or `struct` name and the type of the variable you will be accessing.  So your `choice` variable would be a `ReferenceWritableKeyPath<YourClass,ColoresDeSalidas>`.

Here is a standalone example:

```
enum ColoresDeSalidas : String {
    case Negra
    case Blanca
    case Roja
    case Azul
    case Verde
}

class Foo {
    var backTees = false
    var option = 1

    var colorHcpBackTees1: ColoresDeSalidas = .Negra
    var colorHcpBackTees2: ColoresDeSalidas = .Blanca
    var colorHcpFrontTees1: ColoresDeSalidas = .Roja
    var colorHcpFrontTees2: ColoresDeSalidas = .Blanca

    var choice: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Foo,ColoresDeSalidas> {
        if backTees && option == 1 { return \.colorHcpBackTees1 }
        if backTees && option == 2 { return \.colorHcpBackTees2 }
        if !backTees && option == 1 { return \.colorHcpFrontTees1 }
        if !backTees && option == 2 { return \.colorHcpFrontTees2 }

        fatalError("We were supposed to return a keyPath for choice")
    }

    func test() {
        backTees = true
        option = 2

        print("Before: \(self.colorHcpBackTees2)")

        // Now update the correct property using the choice KeyPath
        self[keyPath: choice] = .Azul

        print("After: \(self.colorHcpBackTees2)")

        backTees = false
        option = 1

        // Assign it to another variable, just to show you can
        let choiceFront1 = choice

        option = 2

        // choiceFront1 still refers to !backTees and option 1
        // even though option and choice have changed
        print("colorHcpFrontTees1 = \(self[keyPath: choiceFront1])")
        colorHcpFrontTees1 = .Verde
        print("colorHcpFrontTees1 = \(self[keyPath: choiceFront1])")

    }
}
```

**Run the test:**

```
Foo().test()
```

**Output:**

> ```
> Before: Blanca
> After: Azul
> colorHcpFrontTees1 = Roja
> colorHcpFrontTees1 = Verde
> ```

Comment: Works like a charm, I didn't even have to make changes to my variables or create any new structure, I simply added the choice variable as shown inside the function and simply changed Foo to the class of my viewController.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

To clean the code you could wrap the logic for initialising the properties within the enum itself.

```
extension ColoresDeSalidas {
  init?(isBackTee: Bool, option: Int) {
    switch (isBackTee, option) {
    case (true, 1): self = .colorHcpBackTees1
    case (true, 2(: self = .colorHcpBackTees2
    case (false, 1): self = .colorHcpFrontTees1
    case (false, 2): self = .colorHcpFrontTees2
    default: return nil  //or assign a default and make non-failable
}
```

And then you can initialise / update with:

```
let myVar = ColoresDeSalidas(isBackTee: true, option: 1)
```